# Forced to log into my Xbox One profile with my email address

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

I like to turn off my Xbox One when I'm done using it since I don't have it hooked up through my TV. Therefore, every time I turn on my Xbox, I can't auto sign into my profile. Instead, I'm forced to enter in my email password each and every time I want to boot up. Anyone know how to get around having to do this? The strange thing is that I have my "Sign-in, security & passkey" set to "No Barriers", and Instant sign-in is activated. Anyone have this issue and able to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe you need to set your profile to have the console as your "Home Console". my Dad turns off his console and i know he doesn't need an email or password every time cause if he did i would be scorning Microsoft for making my life even worse

Comment: A good guess, but my Xbox One is already set as my Home Console.

Comment: Do you have a Kinect? I turn my Xbox off every day and even turn off power. I never have any trouble signing in.